# WorkFusion RPAExpress Exception Handling

Tags: workfusion

I'm using Error Handling in WorkFusion.
Is there a way to see the error message in the catch block i.e. exception occurred block.

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
<log>exception_msg_var</log>
```

or

```
println exception_msg_var
```

exporting exceptions to datastore?

Answer (score 0):

To get the error message in RPA Express, you can keep the code outside of exception handling and then, the software will through error message on its' own. Once you get the type of error (by running the bot once), you can put the solution in catch block by keeping the code inside exceptional handling feature.